# when typing a local musical instrument

Tags: letters-of-the-alphabet

[*Geomungo*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1152&bih=749&q=Geomungo&oq=Geomungo&gs_l=img.12..0l2j0i24l5.1083.1083.0.1934.1.1.0.0.0.0.119.119.0j1.1.0....0...1ac.2.52.img..0.1.119.0q4ymNQzLXk&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=Geomungo&tbm=isch) is a Korean musical instrument. When I type this word, do I have to use capital G, or small g as in *guitar*? For the instrument is used in quite a small area and has not that popularity like the guitar, I'm hesitating to decide which is proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you write it *geomungo* or with the older spelling *komungo* (which is prominent in [Google Books search results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=geomungo,komungo,hyeongeum,hongum&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4;,komungo;,c0;,s0;;komungo;,c0;;Komungo;,c0)), it is a common noun and there is no need to capitalize it unless you would do so anyway—for example at the beginning of a sentence.  I took a look through the results linked above and through some Google main search results and found no reason to think otherwise.